# Is it possible to implement a registry of generic methods base on their types?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Here's a method delegate that I have :

```
delegate void ExceptionHandelr<T>(T exception,out bool handeled) where T:Exception;
```

I would like to have a registry of these kind of method so I could call them based on the type of their methods something like this :

```
var method=ErrorHandlers[typeof(NullReferenceException)];
method(exception as NullReferenceException,out handled);
```

How I can implement this registry? I can't have a `Dictionary<T,Method<T>>` can I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` and than executed the delegate using `DynamicInvoke` method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your replay. This approach will make my code rather ugly :) Is there a way to cast a Delegate to a specific delegate ?

Comment: @Beatles1692 - I wouldn't call it ugly. That's where you get when you use 'too much' generics... ;-)

Comment: I thought we were using generics to get rid of (casts) but it seems that we can't :))

Comment: The problem is that Foo<T1> and Foo<T2> have no common 'base type' you could use in code...

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{
    class MainApp
    {
        public class ExceptionRegistry
        {
            Dictionary<Type, object> registry = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

            private Func<T, bool> Get<T>() where T : Exception
            {
                return registry[typeof(T)] as Func<T, bool>;
            }

            private bool Invoke<T>(T exception) where T : Exception
            {
                return Get<T>().Invoke(exception);
            }

            public bool Invoke(Exception exception)
            {
                MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(exception.GetType());
                var result = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { exception });

                return (bool)result;
            }

            public void Add<T>(Func<T, bool> handler) where T : Exception
            {
                registry.Add(typeof(T), handler);
            }

        }

        static void Main()
        {
            ExceptionRegistry registry = new ExceptionRegistry();

            registry.Add<ArgumentException>((ArgumentException exception) =>
                {
                    // some logic

                    return true;
                });

            Exception ex = new ArgumentException();

            bool result = registry.Invoke(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then we are not using a Generic method delegate no more :)

Comment: No your not.. but is that a problem?

Comment: not in general but I'd like to learn more about Generic methods

Comment: Actually I'd like to define my methods using Lambda Expressions and I don't like to cast the exception in the body of my method.

Comment: Thanks! nice job :) but I think it would be better if we don't mention the exception type in Invoke method .Just call Registry.Invoke(exception)

Comment: Added some reflection so you can call the Invoke method without generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late answer, but I fancied giving it anyway :)

You could use a static, generic helper class to store and retrieve the handlers in a strongly-typed, type-safe fashion:

```
public static class ExceptionHandlers<TEx>
    where TEx : Exception
{
    public static ExceptionHandler<TEx> Handle
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

You'd assign handlers in one place:

```
public static void MyExceptionHandler(MyException exception, out bool handled)
{
    // Handling logic...
}

...

ExceptionHandlers<MyException>.Handle = MyExceptionHandler;
```

...and use them wherever you needed to:

```
try
{
    // Something...
}
catch(MyException myEx)
{
    bool handled;
    ExceptionHandlers<MyException>.Handle(myEx, out handled);
}
```

A single instance of each unique `ExceptionHandler<TEx>` is created at runtime as different `TEx` types are used, and as desired, you've got handlers with no casting :)

It would also be pretty easy to extend this solution to use collections of handlers if required.

Comment: Using a static class as a holder is a good approach.  Two other ways of populating it would be: (1) have a "new" constraint on the generic class, and have the interface either include a factory method which will yield another instance which is initialized according to specified parameters, or a method which will return a (possibly singleton) factory that can make instances with specified parameters, or (2) have the constructor for `ExceptionHandlers<TEx>` check whether type `TEx` has a static method `ExceptionHandler<TEx> GetExceptionHandler()` and cache that method if so.

Comment: Note that it is extremely bad form to have static class constructors throw exceptions.  If Reflection fails to find a suitable method, it should set some fields so that an exception will be thrown when code tries to use the cached value.  Alternatively, the property to get the exception handler could use Reflection the first time it's invoked and then return a cached value after that.  There are many approaches one can use, but one should endeavor to ensure that any exceptions that will be thrown, get thrown when they should--neither sooner nor later.

Comment: All interesting suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

One could have a dictionary such as you describe, but a somewhat better pattern would be to follow the lead of `Comparer<T>`.  Implement a generic type with a static field of a suitable delegate type, along with means of querying the field, or setting it if it hasn't been set yet.  If desired, you could even have the default value of the field be a routine which would examine the type to see if it implements some interface, and make the delegate point to an interface method if appropriate.

Comment: would you please show me some code I didn't get exactly how to do it :)